# why RecyclerView doesn't work in android 9

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-9.0-pie

Although everything works well in android 8 and lower, but my RecyclerView doesn't load anything in android 9.

because I used Picasso in my recyclerView Adapter, I added code bellow to my AndroidManifest but nothing changed:

```
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

this is my RecyclerView XML code which is located in a MotionLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F6F6F6"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_challenge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> note that I have two recyclerView in my layout, the first one, works well
>   but the second one doesn't work!

Comment: What are you experiencing that makes you say it doesn't work? Is there a traceback in the logs that could help us out?

Comment: Hi @Mohammad, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Define a xml file, then add to your manifest
->> android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```